# Writing External URLS from Database with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

A very easy question. I am just getting started with MVC. I have external URL's stored in my database. The following line of markup renders the link www.google.com as  localhost/Home/www.google.com

```
<a href="@item.URL" target="_blank">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a>
```

Where am I going wrong

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't actually render that way but since you have no protocol http:// or http:// in front of it.. it thinks it is a path based on your current page. So - append a protocol in front of it

Comment: <a href="http://@item.URL" target="_blank">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a> worked :) , As did adding http:// to the database URLs  Cheers